# c# Virtual mouse movement and click. Without moving the in use real cursor

Tags: c#, mouse

I would like to be able to simulate a movement and a click of the mouse, without using the real moouse. would use a virtual mouse, because even if my application's launch 10 processes must be able to perform each movement and clicks in different windows.
thanks

UPDATE
"i mean a ghost mouse, 'cause every process that i launch must have a personal mouse"

Comment: Do you mean a ghost mouse? Or do you mean using the cursor that you, the user, control with your mouse?

Comment: i mean a ghost mouse, 'cause every process that i launch must have a personal mouse. thanks!

Comment: so you want to create your own cursor? 
if so, this could help you http://tech.pro/tutorial/732/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors

Comment: No Elior, i need a ghost mouse in every process that i launch. thank you